# Cannot return Array in a void method

Tags: java, arrays, function

During compilation,an error message pops up which says **.class expected** 
The error points to the return statement which returns the array.

```
public static void convertToArray(String pin){
    StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
    sB.append(pin);
    String toConvert = sB.toString();
    int [] splittedValue = new int [toConvert.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < toConvert.length(); i++){
          splittedValue[i] = Character.getNumericValue(pin.charAt(i));
    }
    return splittedValue[]; 
}
```

Comment: if you are just new, start at the beginning. learn decent naming conventions, how to deal with simple issues, and, if you post a question saying "I get an error message", don't forget to say where that error message points to.

Comment: where you declared pinExtracted.

Comment: Also: you are trying to get values out of pinExtracted. Where is that array defined?

Comment: Are you sure your class compiles? From what I can see, you have a returned value from method convertToArray(), but the declared return type for it is void.

Comment: If you get an error you _might_ want to share details about it (e.g. the exact message) and if it contains a line number tell us which line that is as well.

Comment: Looks like you have not compiled you src file

Comment: Actually pinExtracted is splittedValues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *.class expected* is caused by

```
return splittedValue[];
```

You must use `[]` only when you declare an array variable, so change this to

```
return splittedValue;
```

Note that your `convertToArray` method then should have signature

```
public static int[] convertToArray(String pin){
```

There are more errors in the main method, you don't declare variable `pinExtracted` therefore write

```
int[] pinExtracted = convertToArray(Pin);
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I run it, it Says : _java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 0

Comment: @AbhigyanSingh you get the exception if `Pin` does not contain three digits. So you must test the input and reject it if it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks now my problem is Solved .

Answer (score 1):

I think Your output will come like this only correct.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
public class name {
public static void convertToArray(String pin){
    StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
    sB.append(pin);
    String toConvert = sB.toString();
    int [] splittedValue = new int [toConvert.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < toConvert.length(); i++){
          splittedValue[i] = Character.getNumericValue(pin.charAt(i));
    }
   // return splittedValue[]; 
}
public static void Print(int n) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
    String Name1, Name2, Name3;
    String Pin;
    String Names[][] ={ {"Mr.","Mrs.","Miss.","Dr.","Sir","Late","Professor","Gadha","Master","Teacher"},{"Abhigyan","Akashdeep","Anish","Adarsh","Ashutosh","","Anik","Shivam","",""},{"Saha","Mukkherjee","Pandey","Shaw","Bannerjee","Dey","Gupta","Singh","",""} };        
    System.out.println("Enter your 3 digit code name :");
    Pin=br.readLine();
    convertToArray(Pin);
    Name1=Names[0][0]; Name2=Names[1][1]; Name3=Names[2][2];
    System.out.println(Name1+" "+Name2+" "+Name3);
}
}
```

**Output:**

Enter your 3 digit code name :

012

Mr. Akashdeep Pandey